# send email button from custom object

Tags: visualforce, javascript, email-template, custom-button

I am a newbie, and that's the probably reason why I am lost with this problem.
I have two email templates created (one for students, and another for professorial). There is a custom object, and I need two custom buttons on this object tab to email both templates.
Each template is using some custom fields from the custom object.

Template to professors is using these fields:

> Placement__c.Field_Instructor__c
>   Placement__c.Student__c

Template to students is using this:

> Placement__c.Agency__c
>   Placement__c.Field_Instructor__c

Can you please point me to the example, or explain here? Should I create SF custom button, or should I use Javascript button, and how to use it then? And how do I pass the parameters?

EDIT1 :
I found this example, but questions remain: how do I trigger this process from custom object, how to use email templates with example, and how to pass custom object custom fields to template.

[Apex send email example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm)

EDIT2 :
Well, I got something working, but I'd like to know what parameters' tags  correspond to email template fields (e.g. p5, p24 etc.). Where can I find this ?

> /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003&p3_lkid={!Placement__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Placement__c.Id}&p26={!Placement__c.Student_email__c}&p5={!Placement__c.Student_email__c}&p24=" {!Placement__c.Student_email__c}&template_id=00Xe0000000M2FH

I could not figure out parameter to populate "To" field:

[image]

EDIT 3:
I found what I was looking for here:
http://forcetips.blogspot.com/2013/02/url-hack-to-send-email-by-simple-button.html

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override the "Send an Email" button on the Case object - Emails related list](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/how-to-override-the-send-an-email-button-on-the-case-object-emails-related-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways..

1. The easiest is to use AMartin's hack here: https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000KDqCEAW  I use the term hack deliberately, because salesforce may not support this in the future.
2. Create a visualforce button that updates a field on the record and fires off a workflow email alert.  You can choose the email template that email workflow alert fires off of.

Comment: Yes 1) is a hack, but the hack has been around too long for them to break it.  Salesforce has a big aversion to making changes that break peoples functionality.  Craziest is when they [refuse to fix something that is wholly broken because people now expect it to be broken](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/488/594) (see the bug alert for some WTF!!)