# Override 'Send email' button in Case related list

Tags: button-overrides

Is it possible to override the 'Send email' button in Case related list? Can any one give me an idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, its not possible to directly override the 'Send an Email' button. You need to implement a work-around using the following links:

[End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds) - Check the first reply. Static resource mentioned here will comprise mainly of the body mentioned in the below link.

[How to override the "Send an Email" button on the Case object - Emails related list](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/how-to-override-the-send-an-email-button-on-the-case-object-emails-related-l) (First reply)

I have not implemented this, but theoretically this should work.